# remove class from multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list of elements all with unique IDs, and I want to be able to switch between them by clicking on them. So, if the element is on, the class is "plus on", and every other element will be simply "plus". I'm having trouble reverting previously clicked elements back to just "plus", though. This is the code I have that's not working:

```
$(".plus").on("click", function () {
    $(".plus").removeClass("on");
});
```

This part does work, for turning the element on:

```
        function switch(elem) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elem);
        elem.className = 'plus on';
        }
```

I tried putting the click function inside and then before the switch function, but i can't get anything to work.

Comment: Are the `.plus` elements added dynamically after the document is rendered? Have you wrapped `$(".plus").on` in a `document.ready` handler (or is the script at the bottom of the `body`?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple toggle between elements of the same class, you can use a more efficient method by keeping the currently selected element:

```
var $current = null;

$('.plus').on('click', function() {
    if ($current) {
        $current.removeClass('on');
    }
    $current = $(this).addClass('on');
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, if elements are added dynamically, it would be better to use event delegation; for example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.plus', function() {
```

**Important:** Instead of `document` you should choose an element that's an ancestor of your nodes that will not be removed from the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".plus").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

Might be what you mean, works for the current clicked element by toggling the class

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$(".plus").on("click", function () {
    $(".on").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("on");
    });
    $(this).addClass("on");
 });
```